# Как расположить ячейки в uitableview горизонтально (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

По умолчанию элементы таблицы uitableview располагаются так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я же хочу, чтобы они располагались так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. UICollectionView вместо UITableView